# FMDatabase connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

I am working with FMDatabase in my iOS app but I am opening a new connection on almost every query that I need to do.

For example in my CategoryDAO getCategoriesForArticle method I open a new connection. In my ArticleDAO getArticle I open a new connection.

I was thinking on open just one connection in my AppDelegate and use this connection on all my queries. Would it be good? Or is it better to open a new connection just when I need it and then close that connection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just open one connection and consider using FMDatabaseQueue.